# HTML css table width adaptive

Tags: html, css, width, css-tables, adaptive-layout

How to make table width adaptive? That means, if there is enough room, make it 100%; if the table is too wide and it is clipped, make it auto so that the table columns will not be clipped.

```
<div>

   <table class="adaptive-table">

   </table>

</div>
```

Is there a way using CSS?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want use pure CSS this may help you. Set for table.

```
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
```

Now, if your table will be too wide, you can scroll td with option `overflow: auto;`